# Magento 2 : Remove “Settings” Tab in Mobile Menu

Tags: magento2.2.4, mobile-menu, remove

How Can We Remove “Settings” Tab in Mobile Menu ?

[image]

Waiting for the reply!

Comment: what is "settings"? that's not defualt magento

Comment: Yes correct @PhilippSander I am also thinking that one

Comment: DIrty hack You can hide it using CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put this line into your theme directory Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml file:

```
<referenceBlock name="store.settings" remove="true" />
```

Comment: i want to update account to some other name..Then how to do this

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **`Porto Theme`**, you can remove it in your admin panel. Through your custom CSS settings
**Porto → Setting panel → Customization Setting.**

Just add this code:

```
.switcher.language, [aria-controls*="store.settings"] { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Haha +1 too fast ;) But be careful if you are using multistore then it will remove your store switcher too.

Comment: Thanks for the update,Yes,I'm using Porto Theme...it works for me...but "settings" space is also there...it shoudn't be.

Comment: i want to update account to some other name..Then how to do this – Maruti_magento2 just now

Answer (score 3):

Try this using CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .switcher.language, [aria-controls*="store.settings"] { display: none !important; }
}
```

To Fix rest of 2 menu's width set width to 50% using below:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .nav-sections-item-title{width: 50%;}
}
```

Comment: i want to update account to some other name..Then how to do this – Maruti_magento2 just now